# How to translate dataframe to English?

Tags: r

I have a very large R dataframe consisting of hundreds of columns which contains Dutch headers. Is there a way to translate everything to English in a quick way?

| stroopwaffels | klompen |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |

N.B. the data is of the above form, and no, I don't have a dataframe about stroopwaffels and clogs, those are the first two words that come to mind when I think of the Dutch.

Comment: Do you have a Dutch-English dictionary that you can import into R?

Comment: Maybe use Google translation API: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleLanguageR/readme/README.html

Answer (score 0):

Well using the words you provided, it will be hard to get translations. Also it might go wrong on plurals. If you want to use **open source** and a free API you could use wiktionary.org, but it all depends on how common your Dutch words are in your actual data.

1. When no translation is found, we keep the Dutch column name
2. When more names are found we use the first translation found

**working solution**

```
df <- data.frame(1:2, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2)
names(df) <- c("vliegtuig", "hond", "stroopwafel", "stroopwafels")

library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)

dutch <- names(df)

translated <- sapply(dutch, \(q) {
  r <- fromJSON(paste0("https://nl.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=iwlinks&titles=", q, "&iwprop=url&iwprefix=en&format=json"))
  r <- r$query$pages[[1]]$iwlinks[1, 3]
  ifelse(is.null(r), NA, r)
})


newnames <- na.omit(translated)
oldnames <- names(newnames)

setnames(df, oldnames, newnames)

df

#   aeroplane dog syrup_waffles stroopwafels
# 1         1   1             1            1
# 2         2   2             2            2
```

**An example response**

https://**nl**.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=iwlinks&titles=**vliegtuig**&iwprop=url&iwprefix=**en**&format=json

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"query": {
"pages": {
"11995": {
"pageid": 11995,
"ns": 0,
"title": "vliegtuig",
"iwlinks": [
{
"prefix": "en",
"url": "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aeroplane",
"*": "aeroplane"
},
{
"prefix": "en",
"url": "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aircraft",
"*": "aircraft"
},
{
"prefix": "en",
"url": "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/airplane",
"*": "airplane"
},
{
"prefix": "en",
"url": "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plane",
"*": "plane"
}
]
}
}
}
}
```